# How to conditionally invoke a4j:commandButton oncomplete script depending on action outcome

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{myBean.doCalculation}"
                   oncomplete="redirectBrowser()" />
```

However, if there is an error at `myBean.doCalculation()`, then `oncomplete` attribute is always invoked. How do I let it depend on result of action method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for errors in the oncomplete event and redirect when none are found. It can be done like this

```
oncomplete="#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null ? 'redirectBrowser()' : 'doSomethingElse()'}"
```

Comment: There is really no problem with a4j:commandButton and navigation - it's not designed to be used for navigation. One option is to use <redirect/> for navigation.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on JSF 2.0, you can use [`FacesContext#isValidationFalied()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) to check if validation has failed or not:

```
oncomplete="if (#{not facesContext.validationFailed}) redirectBrowser()"
```

However, just performing redirect in the action method is more clean:

```
public String doCalculation() {
    // ...

    if (success) {
        return "nextPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Yet more clean would be to just do the validation by a `Validator`. This way the action method will simply not be invoked at all when the validation has failed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  It was very helpful.  To respectfully disagree with one point, doing the redirect in the action method is less clean -- IMHO allowing redirection by returning a string is a design flaw in Faces...

Comment: It's absolutely not a design flaw. PRG is one of the most commonly used web design patterns: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get However, using POST forms for *plain vanilla* navigation from page X to page Y is in turn absolutely a design flaw (by the developer, not by JSF). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink

Comment: Sorry, lazy's not the word I was looking for.  Nothing wrong with PRG; it's just a clunky syntax is what I'm getting at.  It seems odd to return a string rather than call some redirect method.

Answer (score 2):

Well, just looking for facesContext.maximumSeverity == null is not enough, there may be a warning as current max severity, that should redirect, too. Instead, write a method that looks if there are any max severities of priority error...